# How to find the 'HZ' value from a linux kernel core-dump?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, clock, coredump

Is there a global variable that can be read? From 2.6 kernel, its configurable so I can't be too sure that the default value was indeed used. I am using 'crash' for debugging the kernel core dump.

Answer (score 1):

It is configured during in kernel's .config during compilation. Check your .config file; search for CONFIG_HZ_; in my config HZ is 250(CONFIG_HZ_250=y). Usually, .config file is present inside directories of "/lib/modules/"

Answer (score 0):

Today several Linux kernels don't use a static frequency but change it dynamically during runtime, so there is no global variable you could read.